# Error: adding element with duplicate id

Tags: sapui5

Hi I'm trying to make a split view application in sapui5.
However when I'm trying to select an entry from the master view(left side of the split screen), the view is coming on left side only.
And if I try adding this in the `App.view.js`

```
this.app.addDetailPage(sap.ui.xmlview("Trial", "view.Trial"));
```

It is giving the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Error: adding element with duplicate id 'Trial'
```

Please note that the views used in the app are XML views not JS view

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to reference the view by ID, I would get rid of the ID altogether:

```
this.app.addDetailPage(sap.ui.xmlview("view.Trial"));
```

or otherwise, if the view already has been instantiated, remove it from the DOM after closing / navigating away

Comment: It does remove the error but it also makes the point of writing the above statement unnecessary. As I want the Trial view to come on the detail view side(ie left side) of the split screen.

Comment: If I understand correctly, are you trying to have the `view.Trial` page both in left and right pane? It's not possible to have a control with the same ID in multiple places, just give it a new ID

Comment: I want the view.Trial on the right side. I have tried setting different ids.When the id is different I'm getting an 404 file not found error, if I use the id which I had specified to the view it's giving duplicate id error.

Comment: Can you update your question with your App.js and xml views definition?

Comment: Removing the Ids it does solve my issue as I had the same problem. Before , my page loads with problem only in first time I reload tomcat, after that I keep getting the same errors.It seems ,the page control are cached somehow